# Rewriting $8H(t-\pi)(sint)$ without use of the heaviside function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I was given a differential equation to solve using Laplace transformation. 
and I got a term that had : $-8H(t-\pi)(sint)$

The question asks to rewrite the solution without the use of the heaviside function. How do I go about doing this?  I know it has to be in intervals (i.e. $t\lt \pi$ etc).

The diff eq. is:

$$\ddot y+y=sin2t+(-7+cost)\delta(t-\pi) $$

where $y(0)=0$, $\dot y(0)=1$

Comment: @Moo is there a good resource for that?

Comment: @Moo added it and going through your links

Comment: See the bottom of the second page at: http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-LT3.pdf, the Laplace Transform of the RHS is $\dfrac{2}{s^2+4}-7 e^{-\pi  s}-e^{-\pi  s}$, which should greatly simplfy what you are trying to solve. I will assume you know how to the LT of the LHS. You might also like http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DiracDeltaFunction.aspx

Comment: @Moo my problem is:when $t\lt \pi$ we get that the value of the second term on the RHS is 0. What do we get when $t\gt \pi$? What is the value of the heaviside function? The inverse transform was already completed, just rewriting teh function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a sign error in your function, it should be:

$$\tag 1 f(t) = 8 ~\sin(t)~u(t-\pi)$$

We want to write the function in $(1)$ without the use of the unit step function.

For $(1)$, the unit step function is equal to zero for all times less than $\pi$ and is then just the sine function for times greater than $\pi$.

If we were to plot $(1)$, we would get:

[image]

We can write $(1)$ as a piece-wise function without the unit step function as:

$$f(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
~~~~0 & : t \lt \pi\\
8 \sin t  & :t \ge \pi
\end{array}
\right.$$

Plot this function and verify it produces the same plot as above.